# any way to download the data with custom queries from url in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, request

I want to download the data from `USDA` site with custom queries. So instead of manually selecting queries in the website, I am thinking about how should I do this handier in python. To do so, I used `request`, `http` to access the url and read the content, it is not intuitive for me how should I pass the queries then make a selection and download the data as `csv`. Does anyone knows of doing this easily in python? Is there any workaround we could download the data from url with specific queries? Any idea?

**this is my current attempt**

here is the [url](https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail?&repType=summary&portal=ls&category=Retail&species=BEEF&startIndex=1) that I am going to select data with custom queries.

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd

url="https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail?&repType=summary&portal=ls&category=Retail&species=BEEF&startIndex=1"
s=requests.get(url).content
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

so before reading the requested json in `pandas`, I need to pass following queries for correct data selection:

```
Category = "Retail"
Report Type = "Item"
Species = "Beef"
Region(s) = "National"
Start Dates = "2020-01-01"
End Date = "2021-02-08"
```

it is not intuitive for me how should I pass the queries with requested json then download the filtered data as `csv`. Is there any efficient way of doing this in python? Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you can filter the results on the site and then copy the URL on the filtered page.

Comment: @KJDII I mean how can we do this in a pythonic way instead of selecting manually then submit the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few details

- simplest format is text rather that HTML.  Got URL from HTML page for text download
- `requests(params=)` is a `dict`.  Built it up and passed,  no need to deal with building complete URL string
- clearly text is space delimited,  found minimum of double space

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd

url="https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail"
p = {"repType":"summary","species":"BEEF","portal":"ls","category":"Retail","format":"text"}
r = requests.get(url, params=p)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

|  | Date | Region | Feature Rate | Outlets | Special Rate | Activity Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 02/05/2021 | NATIONAL | 69.40% | 29,200 | 20.10% | 81,650 |
| 1 | 02/05/2021 | NORTHEAST | 75.00% | 5,500 | 3.80% | 17,520 |
| 2 | 02/05/2021 | SOUTHEAST | 70.10% | 7,400 | 28.00% | 23,980 |
| 3 | 02/05/2021 | MIDWEST | 75.10% | 6,100 | 19.90% | 17,430 |
| 4 | 02/05/2021 | SOUTH CENTRAL | 57.90% | 4,900 | 26.40% | 9,720 |
| 5 | 02/05/2021 | NORTHWEST | 77.50% | 1,300 | 2.50% | 3,150 |
| 6 | 02/05/2021 | SOUTHWEST | 63.20% | 3,800 | 27.50% | 9,360 |
| 7 | 02/05/2021 | ALASKA | 87.00% | 200 | .00% | 290 |
| 8 | 02/05/2021 | HAWAII | 46.70% | 100 | .00% | 230 |

Comment: I get an idea of making a param list then pass it from [this](https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail?runReport=true&portal=ls&startIndex=1&category=Retail&repType=item&species=BEEF&region=NATIONAL&grade=0&cut=0&dataType=None+Selected&operator=%3C&dataValue=&repDate=03%2F01%2F2019&endDate=02%2F08%2F2021&compareLy=No), but how do we do this easier like parameters I want to pass in above? Any idea?

Comment: `u = "https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail?&repDate=03%2F01%2F2019&cut=0&repType=item&endDate=02%2F08%2F2021&dataType=None+Selected&dataValue=&operator=%3C&species=BEEF&grade=0&compareLy=No&portal=ls&category=Retail&region=NATIONAL&runReport=true&format=text"
p = urllib.parse.parse_qs(u)
`. will build a param dict from a URL.  Then you can decide how you want to build it programatically

Comment: I think your above attempt is cool except I can't select time range. for instance here is my param list: `p = {"repType":"summary","species":"BEEF","portal":"ls","category":"Retail","format":"text", "Cut": "All", "Grade":"All", "Regions": "National", "Start Date": "2019-10-01", "End Date": "2021-02-05"}`, I tried this in your attempt, but not getting right dataframe though. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just format the query data in the url - it's actually a REST API:

To add more query data, as @mullinscr said, you can change the values on the left and press submit, then see the query name in the URL (for example, start date is called `repDate`).

If you hover on the Download as XML link, you will also discover you can specify the download format using `format=<format_name>`. Parsing the tabular data in XML using pandas might be easier, so I would append `format=xml` at the end as well.

```
category = "Retail"
report_type = "Item"
species = "BEEF"
regions = "NATIONAL"
start_date = "01-01-2019"
end_date = "01-01-2021"

# the website changes "-" to "%2F"
start_date = start_date.replace("-", "%2F")
end_date = end_date.replace("-", "%2F")

url = f"https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail?runReport=true&portal=ls&startIndex=1&category={category}&repType={report_type}&species={species}&region={regions}&repDate={start_date}&endDate={end_date}&compareLy=No&format=xml"

# parse with pandas, etc...
```

Comment: The above attempt is not working for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Adam It returns a (seemingly) valid XML string when I use `requests.get(url).content`. What isn't working for you?